# MVC one or separate models?

Tags: oop

I'm working on a web site that has two different possibilities for client support. In both of them he is required to submit a small form with some of the needed fields.

I implemented one of them using a pretty basic model containing the necessary properties like name, email and couple of others more, where the user enters his/hers data, and if all the fields are valid, he is redirected to a screen that congratulates him on the successful submission of the form.

The second one requires almost the same input from the client as the first one, except for one field that is not included, and there are some other fields that the client must fill in order to get the second type of support.

I was wondering would it be a good idea to use the same model for both the views although neither won't use all of the properties, since creating two distinct models with half the same properties seems like a waste to me.

Comment: You can create base model class with common properties and inherit it by two  specific model classes.

Comment: why do people downvote this question? It's not a MVC- but rather a reusability-specific question, but if the OP knew that the question wouldn't be there.

Comment: you can also reuse parts of the View in case that you are not aware of that.

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum You're right, it's not an MVC specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use inheritance for your models:

Let's say, input 1 requires properties `A`, `B` and `C`. Input 2 requires `B`, `C` and `D`.

Create two classes:

```
 public abstract class MyThingyBase
 {
      public int B { get; set; }
      public int C { get; set; }
 }

 public class Input1 : MyThingyBase 
 {
      public int A { get; set; }
 }

 public class Input2 : MyThingyBase 
 {
      public int D { get; set; }
 }
```

this way both classes have all properties they need without code duplication. You can even share the handling code for `B` and `C` by placing it in something that works with the `MyThingyBase` class.

Comment: Wow, this was probably in the first academic year in school. Shouldn't have forgotten it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but the best thing to do would be to create one model with all the properties that both forms would submit and then create the second model which will extend the first one and be more specific.